# Cohen marries a Divorced Woman 

Tags: riddle, kohen-priest, marriage

Where do we find in Tanach 2 famous Kohanim who married divorced women?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Midrash say that Moses divorced Tzipporah when he went to Egypt and presumably remarried when Yitro brought her back.

Comment: Michael Rosenberg, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting answer! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register/login, above.

Comment: You got 1 but there is two

Comment: this may have been prior to Matan Torah, and Moshe was a Levi?

Comment: משה ואהרון בכוהניו . Moshe is counted as a Kohen becuase he did the temple service during the 7 days of the inauguration of the mishkan.

Comment: And the second one was way earlier and gave Matnas Kehunah to someone else

Comment: Then I think the question should be changed to Which 2 famous Kohanim prior to Matan Torah...............

Comment: The nature of a riddle is to make it challenging not easier

Answer (score 2):

Amram was the eldest, and so (before *Mattan Torah*) was the *kohen* of the family, and he took back Yocheved whom he’d divorced.  (I somehow don’t think that qualifies as a “famous *kohen*”, though…)

Comment: Good try but no cigar

Answer (score 1):

Avraham Avinu remarried Ketura which according to Rashi was Hagar.

Comment: You got the second answer but since you had a hint I am going to give it to Mister rosenberg